# glBindFramebuffer causes an "invalid operation" GL error when using the GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER target

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

I'm using OpenGL 3.3 on a GeForce 9800 GTX. The reference pages for 3.3 say that an invalid operation with glBindFramebuffer indicates a framebuffer ID that was not returned from glGenFramebuffers. Yet, I output the ID returned by glGenFramebuffers and the ID I send later to glBindFramebuffer and they are the same.

The GL error goes away, however, when I change the target parameter in glBindFramebuffer from GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER to GL_FRAMEBUFFER. The documentation says I should be able to use GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER. Is there any case in which you can't bind to GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER? Is there any harm from using GL_FRAMEBUFFER instead of GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER? Is this a symptom of a larger problem?

Comment: Are you making the call from another thread than the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)` works when `glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER)` does not, and we're *not* talking about the EXT version of these functions and enums (note the lack of "EXT" suffixes), then it's likely that you may have done something wrong. GL_INVALID_OPERATION is the error you get when multiple combinations of parameters that depend on different state are in conflict. If it were just a missing enum, you should get GL_INVALID_ENUM.

Of course, it could just be a driver bug too. But there's no way to know without knowing what your code looks like.

Comment: The program was written for OpenGL 2.2. If I'm using glut, can I assume that since glGetString(GL_VERSION) tells me 3.3 that the context I am using is 3.3? In other words, the program might be assuming the EXT version of framebuffers.

Comment: @Phineas: There is no OpenGL 2.2. There's 2.1, and 3.2, but not 2.2.